# Image display issue with PHP

Tags: php, image, apache, header, gd

I'm currently trying to display an image using PHP GD functions on a local website hosted by Apache (XAMPP). However, my navigator (Google chrome) displays a black screen with a white square instead of the red string. When I delete the "header(...)" line, it displays the image as text.
Does the error come from the Apache server ? Or from the "header(...)" line ? Or from somewhere else ?

Thanks a lot

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
 <title> Title </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  header("Content-Type: image/png");

  $im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
  imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
  
  imagepng($im);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at PHP Doc for `header()`:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
"Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file."

Don't output HTML tags (nor whatever else) before calling `header()`